# Backbone.js listenTo window resize throwing [object Object] has no method 'apply' error

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

**Problem:**

I'm trying to attach a resize event to the window from a view using the new listenTo() method in Backbone.js.  The event seems to bind to the window, however, when the window is actually resied the following error is thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply' 
>   jquery.js:2 p.event.dispatch
>   jquery.js:2 p.event.add.g.handle.h

**Here is the code that attaches the event to the view:**

```
this.listenTo($(window),"resize", this.resizeContext, this));
```

**Here is the resizeContext function:**

```
  resizeContext: function(event) {

            console.log("resizing context for "+this.id);

            this.setHeight();

            // trigger resize event (use event bus)
            this.options.vent.trigger("resize", event);

        }
```

**Note:** using the standard `$(window).on("resize",this.resizeContext)` attaches the event and runs as it should.  I am trying to take advantage of the new `stopListening()` feature that is added to `view.remove();`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The new `listenTo` and `stopListening` are methods of the `Backbone.Events` mixin, and they can only be used to listen to Backbone events which are triggered with `.trigger`, such as the built-in `collection:add`, or `model:change` events.

That means that you won't be able to utilize the `stopListening` functionality for DOM events such as `window:resize`.

Consider overriding the `View.remove`method instead.

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize:function() {
    $(window).on("resize",this.resizeContext)
  },

  remove: function() {
    $(window).off("resize",this.resizeContext);
    //call the superclass remove method
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I notice that you are using `.off()` to remove the event.  I was using unbind() to remove them, however, they were still firing, even after calling `view.remove()` and `view.unbind()`.  Does `unbind()` only remove Backbone events and should I be using `off()`?

Comment: @Zengineer, the naming is a bit confusing: Backbone objects (like View) have both `on/off` and `bind/unbind` methods, that are just two names for the same thing: (un)binding **Backbone** events. jQuery also has methods called `on/off` an `bind/unbind` that (un)bind **jQuery** (DOM) events. In both cases you should be using the `on/off` variants, because `bind/unbind` are deprecated.

Comment: I'm seeing the light now.  Thanks!

Comment: Just remember that if you will be using .bind(someObj) within .on, like: $(window).on("resize",this.resizeContext.bind(this)), .bind() creates new function and it will not be unbind. Either you can define function with .bind() in the first place, like: this.resizeContext = function(){ ... }.bind(someObj), or you can use event naming like: $(window).on("resize.uniqueName",this.resizeContext.bind(someObj)), $(window).off("resize.uniqueName");

Answer (score 10):

If you want to keep using `listenTo` you might want to use following one off wrapper for DOM elements:

```
/**
 * Use Backbone Events listenTo/stopListening with any DOM element
 *
 * @param {DOM Element}
 * @return {Backbone Events style object}
 **/
function asEvents(el) {
    var args;
    return {
        on: function(event, handler) {
            if (args) throw new Error("this is one off wrapper");
            el.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
            args = [event, handler];
        },
        off: function() {
            el.removeEventListener.apply(el, args);
        }

    };
}
```

Example:

```
view.listenTo(asEvents(window), "resize", handler);
```

and the listener will be remove automatically on `view.remove()` or `view.stoplistening()`

Here's more complex implementation for multiple event listeners https://gist.github.com/epeli/5927950

Comment: Really like it, feels more backbone

Comment: This looks like a very neat solution!

Comment: One addition though, add context as an argument to get binding right. First `on: function(event, handler, context) {` then `el.addEventListener(event, handler.bind(context), false);`.

Comment: Backbone 1.2.1 currently uses `internalOn`, so this isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In my code, I need to do 
    *.debounce(*(this.resizeContext).bind(this)).

Which makes it harder to be turned off.  As a dirty solution, I just turn off all 'resize' listener when remove the view.
I guess in the new view, if there is any resize listener, it will be turned on again.

```
remove: function() {
    $(window).off("resize");
    //call the superclass remove method
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: If you want to use debounced version of your handler and keep other 'resize' event handlers to be untouched, use jquery namespaces to bind/unbind events like `$(window).on("resize.myspace", _.debounce(...)); $(window).off("resize.myspace");`

Comment: Thanks! Good idea to adopt event space.